# laravel elixir browserify, separate output files

Tags: gulp, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I keep my vue.js option objects in separate js files in a folder, so that they're able to load at different views.

this is how the elixir browserify part currently look like

```
mix
  .browserify(path1+'teacher.roster.js', path2+'teacher.roster.timeline.js')
  .browserify(path1+'student.roster.js', path2+'student.roster.timeline.js')
  .browserify(path1+'parent.roster.js', path2+'parent.roster.timeline.js')
  .browserify(path1+'teacher.plan.js', path2+'teacher.plan.js')
 ......
 ......
```

and the list goes on...

I tried to use fs.readdir and do browserify in the callback. but it doesn't seem to work that way.

```
fs.readdir(path1, function(e, files) {
  for(var i in files) {
    mix.browserify(path1 + '/' + files[i], path2 + files[i]);
  }
});
```

I can't figure out the right implementation on this gulp/elixir things